# Pytorch LSTM Prediction not learning

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, lstm, prediction

I'm using a LSTM model to predict BABA stock price using this dataset: "/kaggle/input/price-volume-data-for-all-us-stocks-etfs/Data/Stocks/baba.us.txt".

I'm not sure why my model is not learning and the y_test_prediction is so different from the actual y_test. I really appreciate your help as I'm beginning to learn machine learning. Thank you!

I have scaled the data with minMaxScaler before splitting it. This is how I split the data:

```html
x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test = [], [], [], []
lags = 3

for t in range(len(train_data)-lags-1):
    x_train.append(train_data[t:(t+lags),:])
    y_train.append(train_data[(t+lags),:])

for t in range(len(test_data)-lags-1):
    x_test.append(test_data[t:(t+lags),:])
    y_test.append(test_data[(t+lags),:])    
    
x_train = torch.FloatTensor(np.array(x_train))
y_train = torch.FloatTensor(np.array(y_train))
x_test = torch.FloatTensor(np.array(x_test))
y_test = torch.FloatTensor(np.array(y_test))

x_train = np.reshape(x_train,(x_train.shape[0],x_train.shape[1],1))
x_test = np.reshape(x_test,(x_test.shape[0],x_test.shape[1],1))

print(x_train.shape)
print(y_train.shape)
print(x_test.shape)
print(y_test.shape)
```

This is my LSTM model:

```html
input_dim = 1
hidden_layer_dim = 32
num_layers = 1
output_dim = 1


class LSTM(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_dim,hidden_layer_dim, num_layers, output_dim ):
        super(LSTM, self).__init__()
        
        self.input_dim = input_dim
        self.hidden_layer_dim = hidden_layer_dim
        self.num_layers = num_layers
        self.output_dim = output_dim
        
        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(input_dim, hidden_layer_dim,num_layers,batch_first = True)
        self.fc = nn.Linear(hidden_layer_dim, output_dim)
        
    def forward(self, x):
        # initial hidden state & cell state as zeros
        h0 = Variable(torch.zeros(self.num_layers, x.size(0), self.hidden_layer_dim))
        c0 = Variable(torch.zeros(self.num_layers, x.size(0), self.hidden_layer_dim))

        # lstm output with hidden and cell state
        output, (hn, cn) = self.lstm(x, (h0,c0))
        # get hidden state to be passed to dense layer
        hn = hn.view(-1, self.hidden_layer_dim)
        output = self.fc(hn)

        return output
```

This is my training:

```html
num_epochs = 100
learning_rate = 0.01

model = LSTM(input_dim,hidden_layer_dim, num_layers, output_dim)

loss = torch.nn.MSELoss()    # mean-squared error for regression
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)
hist = np.zeros(num_epochs)

# train model
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    outputs = model(x_train)
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    
    #get loss function
 
    loss_fn = loss(outputs, y_train.view(1,-1))
    hist[epoch] = loss_fn.item()
    
    loss_fn.backward()
    optimizer.step()
    
    if epoch %10==0:
        print("Epoch: %d, loss: %1.5f" % (epoch, hist[epoch]))
```

This is the training loss and prediction vs actual

[training loss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HCoIj.png)

[prediction vs actual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bYrN.png)

Comment: How does your training loss look like?

Comment: For starters share the loss curve over the steps. You are checking your loss over 10 epochs which is surely too much for debugging. At the time of debugging you should what the curve on the steps, not even the epoch.

Comment: I've added the charts for training loss and prediction vs actual. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Is your input data shape correct?...because if `batch_first=False`, then the shape should be  in the form (seq_length, batch_size, hidden_size)

Answer (score 0):

You are initialising hidden layers every time forward is being called, which might cause errors with backprop. You do not even have to initialise them. PyTorch takes care of that for you. You can check [this](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/nlp/sequence_models_tutorial.html#example-an-lstm-for-part-of-speech-tagging) implementation for the details. Also, as a side note, you might want to take a look at PyTorch dataloaders(just an easier way to make splits).